# Cartopy Installation issues

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, pip, cartopy, proj

I have a problem installing cartopy. I installed all the dependencies that are required to install it, however, when I try to install it from project interpreter > pip, it gives the following errors.

```
setup.py:168: UserWarning: Unable to determine GEOS version. Ensure you have 3.3.3 or later installed, or installation may fail.
    warnings.warn(
  setup.py:224: UserWarning: Unable to determine Proj version. Ensure you have 4.9.0 or later installed, or installation may fail.
    warnings.warn(
  Proj version 0.0.0 is installed, but cartopy requires at least version 4.9.0.
```

Despite installing GEOS and PROJ 6.3.1, there's a problem determining them. I followed the steps on Github to install GEOS (That gives at the end(OSGeo4W shell)) and for PROJ as well.

What could be the problem and how to verify that GEOS and PROJ 6.3.1 correctly installed?

please if you suggest some commands to write, mention the corresponding window (cmd,python terminal).

feel free to ask for more details.

I am using jetbrains pycharm,py 3,windows64.

Comment: Can you run `geos-config --version` in your `cmd`?

Comment: thanks, i used conda so it's fine now

Answer (score 0):

I just solved this issue and maybe it can help you an others with how I overcame the same problem.  I am on a RH 7 workstation by the way.

First you must install the pgdg-common repo from the PostGRES SQL site.

With this repo you will have access to several version of proj (From 6.2 up through 7.2).

In my case I installed the proj7.2 and proj7-2-devel

Then the next problem was the directories where proj was installed.  It uses /usr/proj72
So you can use links to link the /usr/proj72 to /usr/proj or copy the files to correct directories.

Then rerun the pip3 install cartopy and the setup.py will recognize the proj72 installation.